# My do-while statement doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean, do-while

I'm completely new to coding and I was wondering if you guys can help me. This is part of a code in which you battle a vampire, RPG style. My program does not loop back to my characters turn after I set the turn number to one near the bottom of the code, why is this?

```
/**
* Created by f on 7/30/2014.
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class rpgBattle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declarations
    int charHp = 3941;
    int enemyHp = 5200;
    String charName;
    int numDmg;
    int dmgMultiplier = 1;
    String playerInputSt;
    int playerInput;
    int turn = 1;
    int miss;

    //Processes
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name.");
    charName = user_input.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("A vampire emerged!");
    do {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(charName + "'s HP: " + charHp + "/3941");
                System.out.println("The Vampire's HP: " + enemyHp + "/5200");
                System.out.println("What will you do?");
                System.out.println("Enter the number corresponding to the action you would like to perform.");
                System.out.println("1. Attack");
                System.out.println("2. Defend");
                System.out.println(turn);
                playerInputSt = user_input.next();
                playerInput = Integer.parseInt(playerInputSt);
                if (playerInput == 1) {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    miss = rand.nextInt(19);
                    if (miss == 0) {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("The Vampire protected itself.");
                        numDmg = 0;
                    } else {
                        numDmg = rand.nextInt(100) + 550;
                    }
                    enemyHp = enemyHp - numDmg / 1;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(charName + " attacks!");
                    System.out.println("The Vampire took " + numDmg / dmgMultiplier + " damage!");
                    turn = 2;
                } else if (playerInput == 2) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(charName + " guards");
                    System.out.println(charName + " recovered 394 HP!");
                    charHp = charHp + 394;
                    dmgMultiplier = 2;
                    turn = 2;
                };
    } while (charHp > 0 && enemyHp > 0 && turn !=2);
    do {
        Random rand = new Random();
        miss = rand.nextInt(19);
        if (miss == 0) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(charName + " braced himself.");
            numDmg = 0;
        } else {
            numDmg = rand.nextInt(500) + 200;

            charHp = charHp - numDmg / dmgMultiplier;
        }
        System.out.println("The Vampire attacks!");
        System.out.println(charName + " took " + numDmg / dmgMultiplier + " damage!");
        dmgMultiplier = 1;
        turn = 1;
    } while (turn == 2);
}
}
```

Comment: This is a good time to learn how to debug.  Insert System.out.println statements at appropriate places in the code to see where you get and what values you have at each step.

Comment: Where do you decrease charHp ?

Comment: charHp hasn't been added to the equation since regardless of turn or enemyHp, the program still continues to run.

Comment: but your third condition will always be satified causing your while loop to continue forever

Comment: charHp is initialized to 3941 and nowhere you are decreasing it. Your first loop contains -- while (charHp > 0) -- it will never end.

Answer (score 0):

It will never end because in the top level loop, the condition to get out is that the character's health drops below 0. However, you are never decreasing his HP. You are only decreasing the vampire's HP, but not the character. If you want the game to end, make the vampire attack the character too. That way, in some point his HP will drop below 0 and the game will end.

However, to make it more realistic, you should make the game end when the HP of the vampire OR the character are 0, and not when both of them are below 0. To achieve that, instead of using 3 loops, use 2, but changing the condition so that when either one of them has no HP, it will end:

```
do {
    do {
        ...
    } while (turn == 1);
} while (charHp > 0 && enemyHp > 0);
```

Comment: In addition to that, I should no longer be allowed to input commands once I switch to turn 2. However, when I switch to turn two, I can still input commands. Why is that?

Comment: Because you have a loop inside a loop, so even if the condition of the inner loop (`turn == 1`) does not apply, if the one of the outer loop (`charHp > 0 && enemyHp > 0`) is still true, it will continue iterating. If you want to exit when the turn is 2, or the character's hp or the vampire's hp is below 0, use only one loop with the following condition: `(charHp > 0 && enemyHp > 0 && turn != 2)`.

Comment: The game can end. However this requires defending a ridiculous number of times (5450457), i.e. when the `charHp` overflows. I guess nobody wants to play this game to the end ;)

Comment: So, after fixing what you've told me, I noticed changing the turn number back to 1, doesn't allow me to put in another input. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You wanted the program to exit once it reached turn 2. So once it gets to turn 2, there is no chance of changing it again.

Comment: I want it to loop back and forth between turn 1 and turn 2 until either enemyHp or charHp falls to zero or lower. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Create another question, you cannot ask 4 in the same one. However, you should learn a little bit more about programming before doing that. Go somewhere like coursera or codecademy for the basics, and learn about looping and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Without spending too much time analyzing all of your code, it looks like you have nested a Do..While Loop for charHp and a Do..While Loop for enemyHp. I think you need only one Do..While Loop that loops until **either** charHp or enemyHp is zero.

```
        do {
            do {

               //.... Lots of code removed for brevity in the answer .....

                } while (turn == 1);
        } while ((enemyHp > 0) && (charHp > 0));
```

or should it be like this, with only one Do..While Loop

```
        do {

               //.... Lots of code removed for brevity in the answer .....

        } while ((turn == 1) && (enemyHp > 0) && (charHp > 0));
```

Comment: In addition to that, I should no longer be allowed to input commands once I switch to turn 2. However, when I switch to turn two, I can still input commands. Why is that?

Comment: Because, at the top of your Do..While Loop, you prompt for and accept commands.

Comment: But doesn't the do-while loop only work on turn 1? If at the bottom of my code, I change it to turn two, how does that work?

Comment: Yes. If that is not what you want, what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the variable turn ? Once a valid value is entered its value will be 2 untill the end of the game so the inner while will always loop only once.
But the the code will still be executed each time as the outer loops continue to loop until a score drops to 0.

If you want to know the number of turns you are playing, you should increase turn:

```
turn++;
```

and remove the most inner while loop.

If you want to loop until the user has entered a valid value, you should initialise turn at the beginning of the most inner loop:

```
    turn=1;
```

good luck.